# windows mobile 6.1 wlan slow reconnect

Tags: windows-mobile, wlan

We have an app installed on Windows Mobile 6.1, Symbol/Motorola MC5590, which communicates via a WLAN connection. The devices go to sleep after a few minutes, and so does the WLAN. But after getting the device active, it takes at least 7, but often 15 seconds to reconnect the WLAN.

We have the same setup with Windows Mobile 2003 second edition on Symbol MC5040, and within a few seconds the connection is active. That functions great.

Any ideas on how to speed up the reconnect time, after the device was asleep? Tia mucho for any recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

While not being able to find anything in Windows Mobile to speed up the reconnect time to the WLAN (except for keeping the device out of standby, which drains the battery to fast),

we now have a seperate thread in the application that polls the network every 30 seconds. At the moment we are testing if this at least keeps the connection alive, and we'll see what this is going to do for the battery life.